# Show that the Neumann Problem Has no Solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, laplacian

I am given the Partial BVP as follows:

$$
\ u_{rr}+u_{\theta\theta} = 0 ,(r<1,-\pi\leq\theta<\pi)
\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}= sin^2\theta,(-\pi\leq\theta<\pi)
$$
This has no solution, and apparently the reason why is quite simple. I'm having trouble seeing it. And apparently if the Laplacian term is made to be $u_{rr}+u_{\theta\theta}=1$, a solution exists. Any insight as to why?

Comment: Wait, so does it not exist in general for arbitrary boundary conditions? Or just for these boundary conditions?

Comment: From what my textbook says, it doesn't exist when the laplacian = 0, but does exist when the laplacian = 1. The boundary conditions do not change. This is from a section dealing with green's functions, if that provides any more useful information.

Comment: Admittedly I don't know the answer to your question, but what textbook is this? I've been wanting to start learning about PDEs, and this looks like a good reference.